# How do I disable the ctrl + space hotkey for switching keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, awesome-wm

I started using AwesomeWM, and use both Dvorak and Qwerty keyboard layouts. The default keybinding for switching keyboard layouts is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. That also happens to be the shortcut for code completion in Eclipse and IntelliJ. How do I disable the shortcut for switching the keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the keyboard applet, and choose 'Preferences'. There you can find the 'Next input method'. Click the ellipsis (...), press 'Delete' and select 'OK'. Done!